# Why is musicSrv null?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Server connection:

```
    private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder)service;
        //get service
        musicSrv = binder.getService();
        Log.i("Test",binder.getService().toString());
        //pass list
        musicSrv.setList(songList);
        musicBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicBound = false;
    }
};
```

Where I get an error:

```
    public void songPicked(View view){
    musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
    musicSrv.playSong();
    Log.d("Item clicked","Song picked"+Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
    if(playbackPaused){
        setController();
        playbackPaused=false;
    }
    controller.show(0);
}
```

MusicService.java

```
    package com.musicplayer;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.ServiceConnection;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.IBinder;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Binder;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.util.Random;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;

    import com.lyricscloud.R;

    public class MusicService extends Service implements
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

//media player
private MediaPlayer player;
//song list
private ArrayList<Song> songs;
//current position
private int songPosn;

private String songTitle="";
private static final int NOTIFY_ID=1;


private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
    songs=theSongs;
}

public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
    MusicService getService() {
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}

public void initMusicPlayer(){
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
}

public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    //initialize position
    songPosn=0;
    //create Player
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    initMusicPlayer();


}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopForeground(true);
}


public void playSong(){
    player.reset();
    Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
    songTitle=playSong.getTitle();
    //get id
    long currSong = playSong.getID();
    //set uri
    Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            currSong);
    try{
        player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }
    player.prepareAsync();

}


@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    return false;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return musicBind;
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(player.getCurrentPosition() <= 0){
        mp.reset();
        playNext();
    }
}
public int getPosn(){
    return player.getCurrentPosition();
}

public int getDur(){
    return player.getDuration();
}

public boolean isPng(){
    return player.isPlaying();
}

public void pausePlayer(){
    player.pause();
}

public void seek(int posn){
    player.seekTo(posn);
}

public void go(){
    player.start();
}

public void playPrev(){
    songPosn--;
    if(songPosn <= 0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
    playSong();
}

public void playNext(){
    songPosn++;
    if(songPosn >= songs.size()) songPosn=0;
    playSong();
}


@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    mp.reset();
    return false;
}

public void setSong(int songIndex){
    songPosn=songIndex;
    Log.d("Service", ""+songIndex);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MusicPlayer_Songs.class);
    notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
            .setTicker(songTitle)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("Playing");
    builder.setContentText(songTitle);
    Notification not = builder.build();

    startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
}
}
```

The error

```
08-04 22:50:31.796  23825-23825/com.lyricscloud.dev E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lyricscloud.dev, PID: 23825
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.musicplayer.MusicPlayer_Songs.songPicked(MusicPlayer_Songs.java:47)
            at com.musicplayer.MusicPlayer_Songs$3.onItemClick(MusicPlayer_Songs.java:117)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1478)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3480)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4823)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm not sure whats causing it, I need help please, the app is a musicplayer and whenever I click a list item it gives me that error

onStart() callback:

```
     public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(playIntent==null){
        Log.i("Play Intent","Is null");
        playIntent = new Intent(c, MusicService.class);
        //c is rootView.getContext() from onCreateView()
        c.bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        c.startService(playIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `onServiceConnected` has ever been called?  Maybe you need to wait for it?  I don't know anything about this kind of service, and I don't think we have enough of your code to figure this out anyway, but that seems like the most likely issue based on what I can see.

Comment: I'm sure it's being called the Log printed something which means it's being called, I'm not sure what else to show

Comment: If `musicSrv` were null, `onServiceConnected` should have raised an exception, I think.  I can see three possibilities: (1) something else in your code is setting it to `null` afterwards; (2) you've declared `musicSrv` twice and you're using one that hasn't been set; (3) the NPE isn't on `musicSrv` but on another variable, maybe `view`?  I can't tell from the stack trace which exact line is causing the NPE (which line is 47?), so it might help if you indicated that in your post.

Comment: Do you bind to the service? (context.bindService)? AFAIK, this is the only way to get onServiceConnected called. Even if you bind service, the IBinder returned is certainly not of MusicBinder class, so cast would trigger an error.